# jquery mobile dialog not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog

I'm trying to make a dialog with jquery.mobile-1.0.min.
But the problem is when I click the button, the dialog is not popping up.

why it is not working this dialog?

Here is the fiddle 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/xJ8D3/

- You can check it "Page2" on the menu.

  ## main

  ```
  <nav data-role="navbar" class="menu">
      <a href="#main" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">main</a>
      <a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
      <a href="#page3">Page 3</a>
  </nav>

  <section data-role="content">   
      main  
  </section>

  <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
      <h4>Page Footer</h4>
  </footer>
  ```

  ## page2

  ```
  <nav data-role="navbar" class="menu">
      <a href="#main">main</a>
      <a href="#page2" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Page 2</a>
      <a href="#page3">Page 3</a>
  </nav>

  <section data-role="content">   
      page2 
      <br>

      **<a href="#pagetwo">Click Dialog</a>

      <div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" id="pagetwo">
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <a href="#pageone">Dialog Content</a>
      </div>
      </div>**

  </section>



  <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
      <h4>Page Footer</h4>
  </footer>
  ```

  ## page3

  ```
  <nav data-role="navbar" class="menu">
      <a href="#main">main</a>
      <a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
      <a href="#page3" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Page 3</a>
  </nav>

  <section data-role="content">   
      page3page3  
  </section>

  <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
      <h4>Page Footer</h4>
  </footer>
  ```

Comment: why do you use jquery mobile 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dialog page has to be on the same node level as the other pages. Corrected your fiddle to open page3:

### script:

```
<div data-role="page" id="main">
...
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    
    <section data-role="content">   
         
        <a href="#page3" data-rel="dialog">Click Dialog</a>
        
    </section>
...
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="page3">
...
</div>
```

### jsFiddle:

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/tronc/xJ8D3/1/)

Comment: wow thanks.. i used JQM v1.0 because my dreamweaver sets default as JQM ver1.0. any way i need to update version :)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
**<a href="#pagetwo">Click Dialog</a>
```

to

```
**<a href="#pagetwo" data-rel="dialog">Click Dialog</a>
```